# Pushwoosh Cordova API: Can two different devices ever generate the same HWID?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

Our app uses HWIDs generated by Pushwoosh as a key to differentiate devices. Looking over traffic logs, I am seeing what looks like the same device submitting HTTP requests from several different ISPs over short timeframes.

It appears that different devices from all over the internet are generating the same HWID, which our app is treating as the same device causing issues with users interfering with each other. Our data is showing about 50 requests appear to be from different devices, but using the same HWID.

This makes no sense to me -- from what I've read about HWIDs, they are based on the device serial number, so they should always be unique.

Our mobile app is written in Cordova, and we are getting HWIDs with this code:

```
get_hwid: (evt) =>
 _this = @
 regid = device.uuid

if evt? && evt.detail?
  push_notification_id = evt.detail.deviceToken
else
  push_notification_id = ""

pushNotification = cordova.require("pushwoosh-cordova-    plugin.PushNotification")
pushNotification.getPushwooshHWID (hwid) ->
  _this.debug 'in getPushwooshHWID callback'
  _this.debug '  Pushwoosh HWID: ', hwid
  _this.debug '  push_notification_id: ', push_notification_id
  _this.debug '  regid: ', regid
  _this.emit 'retrieved-hwid',
    regid: regid
    push_notification_id: push_notification_id
    hwid: hwid
```

Has anyone observed the PushWoosh API generate HWIDs that weren't always unique?

The PushWoosh docs say that sometimes HWIDs can change on the same device, but I can't find anything that suggests that they can't be expected to be unique.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HWID's (which are IDFV/IDFA) are unique. The only way they may change (to another unique value) is when user restores a backup on a device.

If you see the same HWID's make sure your Pushwoosh SDK are >= 4.1.2
as outlined here
https://www.pushwoosh.com/blog/pushwoosh-sdk-update-ios-10-makes-difference/